# What is the variable result doing in this javascript function

Tags: javascript

In the code below, if result is set to one, the code returns a number 1024 (2 to the power of 10). If result is set to 2, the code returns the number 2048 (or 2 to the power of 11), BUT if result is set to 3, the code doesn`t return the number 4096 (as I would expect, because 2 to the power of 12) but rather 3072.   Why does it return 3072 if "result" is set to 3, but otherwise if set to 1 and 2 it followers the pattern of power to the 10th and 11th

```
function power(base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
    result *= base;
  return result;
}

show(power(2, 10));
```

Comment: What does it return if result is set to zero? Why does that suggest setting it to one sets it to a "special" value? What does that suggest "result" is used for? (See Jeremiah Willcock's answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, `result` is used as an accumulator.  The code computes `result * base**exponent`; `result` is not part of the exponent.

Comment: Thank you Jeremiah. I understand the initial problem I posed thanks to you, but now I wonder what the purpose/function of an "accumulator" is.  Can you please elaborate its role in this code. I am a total newbie so if possible please put it into very simple language. Cheers.

Comment: The code wants to do `base**exponent`.  You start with 1, then multiply that by `base`, then multiply by `base` again, and so on `exponent` times.  The accumulator `result` keeps the intermediate values in that process.

Comment: Right, it just so happens to work for 1 and 2 because 2^0 = 1 and 2^1 = 2; therefore, starting result as those numbers corresponds to increasing the exponent by 0 or 1.

Comment: Only if `base` is 2; if `base` is something else, you'd need to initialize `result` to that value to act like adding 1 to `exponent`.

Comment: when I set result to 3, it looked as if it multiplied the accumulator by 2**10. In otherwords it didn`t start by multiplying the accumulator by the base.

Comment: It multiplies the accumulator by `base**exponent` eventually, but it does that by computing `result * base**0 = result`, `result * base**1 = result * base`, `result * base**2 = result * base * base`, and so on.  The `result` variable is updated each time with the new product.

Comment: thank you Jeremiah. That makes it clearer for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: @mjmitche, you should accept this answer by clicking the tick to the left.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing yourself.  The thing being raised to some power is your first parameter (in your example 2).  The exponent is the 2nd parameter (10).  Your example works correctly. Pass in 12 as your exponent and you will see your expected result.

The result parameter is just a place holder in which you accumulate your results (2x2x2x2....)

The numbers doing all the work are the ones you pass in as parameters to the function.

So, in your example, you're going to take 2 and multiply it by itself 10 times, each time storing the cumulative result in the variable "result".  The thing that's throwing you off is that result is initially set to 1.  This is never meant to be altered. It's built that way so that if you set your exponent to 0 you will end up with a result of 1 (because any number raised to the zeroth power = 1).

Anyway... don't worry about what result is set to. Focus on how the loop works with the interchangeable variable values that are being passed in, in the function call.

Comment: I know the code works, I`m just trying to understand the purpose of the different elements of the code. I don`t get why the variable result is needed and set to 1, that`s why I started substituting numbers for it to try to figure out its purpose.

Comment: I just edited my answer to address this concern. I think the other posters (and I) were initially unclear as to what was throwing you.

Comment: thanks, it`s clearer now because you said this "It's built that way so that if you set your exponent to 0 you will end up with a result of 1 (because any number raised to the zeroth power = 1)."

Comment: it says i don`t have enough reputation points to upvote answers

Comment: I think anyone can select a "correct" answer, but I was being silly... I'm perfectly ok without any checkmarks or upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Do out the multiplication:

1. 3 * 2 = 6
2. 6 * 2 = 16
3. 12 * 2 = 24
4. 24 * 2 = 48
5. 48 * 2 = 96
6. 96 * 2 = 192
7. 192 * 2 = 384
8. 384 * 2 = 768
9. 768 * 2 = 1536
10. 1536 * 2 = 3072

Multiplication table perhaps? Also, what's wrong with [Math.pow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp), just trying to accomplish it yourself?

Comment: Im trying to understand a javascript tutorial, not do actual math.